# Load external jars to Zeppelin from s3

Tags: apache-spark, jar, apache-zeppelin

Pretty simple objective. Load my custom/local jars from s3 to zeppelin notebook (using zeppelin from AWS EMR).

### Location of the Jar

`s3://my-config-bucket/process_dataloader.jar`

Following [zeppelin documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#2-loading-spark-properties) I opened the interpreter like in the following image and `spark.jars` in the properties name and its value is `s3://my-config-bucket/process_dataloader.jar`

[image]

I restarted the interpreter and then in the notebook I tried to import the jar using the following

`import com.org.dataloader.DataLoader`

but it throws the following

```
<console>:23: error: object org is not a member of package com
       import com.org.dataloader.DataLoader
```

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: There is a typo in your screenshot. "sparsk.jars" should be "spark.jars".

Comment: It does not work without this typo as well, at least in Zeppelin 0.8.1 (latest available in AWS EMR).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late thought but for anyone else who might need this in future try below option,

`https://bucket/dev/jars/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar"` is basically your s3 object url.

```
%spark.dep
z.reset()
z.load("https://bucket/dev/jars/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar")
```

Comment: `%spark.dep` is not the recommended way of adding spark dependencies to Zeppelin and has been removed since Zeppelin 0.9. The following suggests using `spark.jars`
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/interpreter/spark.html#dependency-management